# Is it necessary to check isUpdatable() when process run in system mode/trigger to pass security review process

Tags: security, triggers, salesforce, apex, user-permissions

In salesforce, we have a scenario, on the trigger of the lead object we are updating some records of Campaign. But the user on the behalf of we are running the trigger does not have edit permissions on the campaign. We are not facing any issue in the update of the campaign because the trigger is running the operation in system mode.
Further, we have applied for the security review and made the changes and added the check of the object isUpdatable() and after it, we are not able to update the campaign due to that check which returns false for isUpdatable().

My questions are, Can we pass the security review without applying that isUpdatable() check? if our process has the business logic to update the campaign/opportunity on the behalf of the user who doesn't have permissions on the campaign/opportunity?

If we can not pass the security review with that check then what could be an alternative for it, where one user who doesn't have permission on campaign/opportunity, performs some operation on lead/contact and we want to update the campaign/opportunity in system mode after that operation?

or is it necessary to provide the permissions of campaign/opportunity to that user?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a coding question as such so it might be closed here. Consider cross-posting to https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/

Generally speaking, your app should be simplifying Salesforce. Adding value by being pre-built, pre-tested use case for this customer and saving clicks for the end user. (let's ignore situations like pulling data from other systems, runinng some crazy Excel file generation that SF can't do easily). With that philosophy - you're supposed to respect the System Administrator's wishes when it comes to security. If admin didn't grant Profile X edit access to field Y - the security review answer is that you should detect it. If you can recover gracefully and continue with your program - cool. If it's critical field - throw an error, force the admin to make conscious decision. Because if you're saving clicks - user would face same problem in normal UI. It's not only "describes", it's also about "without sharing" for example.

There's another layer to it - licensing. In the old days "Marketing User" (to access campaigns) was a separate license, you assigned it by clicking checkbox on User but it had to be purchased. Now it's bit simpler, part of the full user license (I think). But there are still situations where you can't access Opportunities for example (Platform License) or can access only Account, Contact and 10 custom objects (Chatter Plus License or whatever is the new name).

If you abuse system mode to fetch data from objects user is not allowed to see (or save to them) - official answer is that SF loses money because of you. Permission should really be assigned and if needed - license purchased. I'm not a lawyer, I don't know who violates the Master Service Agreement with Salesforce, you or the client that installed the app or both. I'd say read the contracts and see what you can do to protect yourself. If that means your app can't be installed by customers on Essentials/Professional (or it can be installed anywhere but can be used only by full users, not by Platform/Chatter/Community) - well, it is what it is. Decide pros and cons, legal consequences if it gets caught...

They're humans, talk with them. Maybe you'll pass review. Better have a rock solid business case why you need to bypass the check though.

P.S. You know you don't have to do describes anymore? Spring'20 goes live this & next week and "WITH SECURITY ENFORCED" and "stripinaccessiblefields" become generally available :)

P.P.S you really need trigger? Workflow, process builder, flow (yuck) - anything to not have code = not need the isAccessible and if it effectively dies on permissions - it's the client's sysadmin's problem?